# Specifying fee amount using bitcoinjs

Tags: transaction-fees, bitcoinjs

I'm currently playing with `bitcoinjs` (https://bitcoinjs.org/) and I'm creating offline transactions that I broadcast over the network after.

I've successfully create my first transaction using this : https://medium.com/@orweinberger/how-to-create-a-raw-transaction-using-bitcoinjs-lib-1347a502a3a

But it seems my transaction is stuck since I haven't put enough fee on it to get it mined.

How using a `var tx = new bitcoin.TransactionBuilder();` can I set the fee to a certain amount ? Is this calculated using a default value ?

Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 2):

The fee is the sum of unspent value in a Transaction.

Aka the value **NOT SENT** by your outputs.

> fee = in - out

For an example,  if we assume the input `aa94ab02c182214f090e99a0d57021caffd0f195a81c24602b1028b130b63e31, 0` has an unspent value of `15000`...

```
var txb = new bitcoin.TransactionBuilder()
txb.addInput('aa94ab02c182214f090e99a0d57021caffd0f195a81c24602b1028b130b63e31', 0)
txb.addOutput('1Gokm82v6DmtwKEB8AiVhm82hyFSsEvBDK', 15000)
```

When we send `15000` to `1Gokm82v6DmtwKEB8AiVhm82hyFSsEvBDK`, the `fee` is the value of the inputs minus the value of outputs.

> in:15000 - out:15000 = fee:0

For a fee to be non-zero, **in > out** is required.